# Why does adding OrderByDescending add a sub-query in LINQ to Entities?

Tags: linq-to-entities

In trying to troubleshoot a problem I noticed that if I do the `LINQ to Entities` query:

```cs
var timeRecords = db.Timesheets
.Where(timesheet => timesheet.TimesheetHeaderID == headerID);
```

I get a query like this:

```sql
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[TimesheetHeaderID] AS [TimesheetHeaderID], 
[Extent1].[StartDateTime] AS [StartDateTime], 
[Extent1].[EndDateTime] AS [EndDateTime], 
[Extent1].[ProjectCode] AS [ProjectCode], 
[Extent1].[TaskCode] AS [TaskCode], 
[Extent1].[WorkDescription] AS [WorkDescription]
FROM [dbo].[Timesheet] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[TimesheetHeaderID] = @p__linq__0
```

but if I add an `OrderByDescending()` like this:

```cs
var timeRecords = db.Timesheets
.Where(timesheet => timesheet.TimesheetHeaderID == headerID)
.OrderByDescending(timesheet => timesheet.StartDateTime);
```

I get a query with a sub-query like this:

```sql
SELECT 
[Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Project1].[TimesheetHeaderID] AS [TimesheetHeaderID], 
[Project1].[StartDateTime] AS [StartDateTime], 
[Project1].[EndDateTime] AS [EndDateTime], 
[Project1].[ProjectCode] AS [ProjectCode], 
[Project1].[TaskCode] AS [TaskCode], 
[Project1].[WorkDescription] AS [WorkDescription]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[TimesheetHeaderID] AS [TimesheetHeaderID], 
    [Extent1].[StartDateTime] AS [StartDateTime], 
    [Extent1].[EndDateTime] AS [EndDateTime], 
    [Extent1].[ProjectCode] AS [ProjectCode], 
    [Extent1].[TaskCode] AS [TaskCode], 
    [Extent1].[WorkDescription] AS [WorkDescription]
    FROM [dbo].[Timesheet] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[TimesheetHeaderID] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[StartDateTime] DESC
```

What is the point of the sub-query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the sub-query is for the "Where" part (Where(timesheet => timesheet.TimesheetHeaderID == headerID), and the main query is for the OrderByDescending part (OrderByDescending(timesheet => timesheet.StartDateTime)).
So I am assuming the internal mechanism of LINQ is to handle each chain command separately.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was going to say something along these lines. We have to guess though. It's probably a way to keep things simple for the query generator while no incurring too many problems for the db's query optimizer.